# Why does my python code run fine in Jupyter but not as a .py script?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a portion of code that's tested fine in Jupyter but fails running as a script.

In Jupyter:

```
#Recombine split values into new field used to group for csv output and filename string
df['CSV_ID']=[f"{a}.{b}@{c}" for a,b,c in zip(df.Param,df.Label,df.ID)] 

df.head(1)
```

[image]

But when I run it in a .py script I get invalid syntax error:

```
    df['CSV_ID']=[f"{a}.{b}@{c}" for a,b,c in zip(df.Param,df.Label,df.ID)]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried erasing and rewriting in IDLE but it doesn' t work

Comment: You are using an older version of Python that doesn't support f-strings (prior to 3.6)

Comment: I'm running Python 3.6.6

Comment: Not according to the error message . Put `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` in the line above it and try running it again

Comment: Ugh, you're right: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=18, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: I need to keep 2.7 because of ArcMap.  Is there a way to specify 3.6 as the interpreter for a specific .py script?